# How to make a program which adds up factorials without using math.factorial?

Tags: python, math, factorial

I have a program which I would like to have ask the user to enter a number, and sum the factorials of each number lower than it down to zero, including itself.  I am not permitted to use the math library and it must use no more than one loop. I tried to create a program, but what I came up was this:

```
number=int(input("enter number: "))
answer=0
for order in range(number, 0, -1):
    answer+=(order*number)
    order-1
print(answer)
```

I feel like this would be one of the steps to create the code, but I still could not come up with it. can someone help?
(I am a student, please do not include too professional terms)

Comment: What does your code do? What trouble did you have? What do you think still needs to be done to do the task you were assigned? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953)
|
[Open letter to students with homework problems](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/39188)

Answer (score 1):

You're currently summing `(order*number)` which isn't the factorial of `order` at all, you need something like

```
answer = 0
for order in range(number, 0, -1):
    answer += factorial(order)
```

---

Where `factorial` could be

- `from math import factorial`
- an iterative approach

  ```
  def factorial(n):
      fact = 1
      for num in range(2, n + 1):
          fact *= num
      return fact
  ```
- a recursive approach:

  ```
  def factorial(n):
      if n < 2:
          return 1
      else:
          return n * factorial(n-1)
  ```

---

Note `range(1, number + 1)` is same as `range(number, 0, -1)` if no order is required, like here

Answer (score 1):

You're currently summing (order*number) which isn't the factorial of order. Here's how I would do it:

```
#Most of the code here is to prevent
#crashing on invalid inputs

def factorial(n: int):
    if n==0: #apply convention that 0!=1
        return 1
    fact=1 #start off with 1
    for i in range(1,n+1): #create a range from 1 to n and multiply
        fact*=i
    return fact

def sum_of_factorials(n: int):
    sum=0
    for i in range(n+1):
        sum+=factorial(i)
    return sum

def get_input():
    number=input("enter number: ") #get input
    try: 
        number=int(number) #turn to integer
        if number<0:
            raise ValueError #go to the except block when negative numbers are inputted
        print(sum_of_factorials(number))
    
    except ValueError: #if can't convert to int try again
        print("Invalid input. Try again.")
        get_input()
get_input()
```

Comment: To get a repeated input asking, in case of wrong input, the preferred way is to wrap around a `while True` (and your try/except inside), It not a very good idea to call the get_input recursivly, in your case it's pretty ok, but if there some more code it can be dangerous for the user

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
number = int(input("enter number: "))
sum = 1
fac = 1
for i in range(1, number+1):
    fac *= i
    sum += fac
print(sum)
```

This approach lets you accumulate both the factorial and the sum in the same loop rather than relying on an external library or additional loops to perform that accumulation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def factorial(n):
    '''Computes the factorial of a non-negative number'''
    assert n >= 0
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
         result *= i
    return result

print(factorial(5))
```

However, it only works for non-negative numbers.